# Two particles moving at consant velocity: how close do they get?

Tags: physics, vectors

A particle was at point $P_1$ at time $t_1$ and is moving at the constant velocity $\vec{v}_1$. Another particle was at $P_2$ at $t_2$ and is moving at the constant velocity $\vec{v}_2$. How close did the particles get to each other and at what time? What conditions are needed for a collision?

Comment: You can work out a formula for the coordinates of the 1st particle at time $t$; call it $(x_1(t),y_1(t))$ if you're in 2 dimensions. Then you can work out a formula for the 2nd particle, call it $(x_2(t),y_2(t))$. Then you can write down the distance between these two points. Then you can minimize the distance by differentiating and setting equal to zero. The algebra's a little easier if you square the distance before you differentiate. Can you follow these instructions? or is there some specific place where you need help?

Answer (score 1):

There's collision at time t if : $\vec{OP_1}+(t-t_1)\cdot \vec{V_1}=\vec{OP_2}+(t-t_2)\cdot \vec{V_2}$, where O is the origin.

If not, $\vec{OP_1}+(t-t_1)\cdot \vec{V_1}-(\vec{OP_2}+(t-t_2)\cdot \vec{V_2})=\alpha\cdot\vec{V_1}\wedge\vec{V_2}+\beta(\vec{V_1}+\vec{V_2})  $

Therefore you have a system with 3 equations (projection on $\vec{x},\vec{y},\vec{z}$) and 3 unknowns $(t,\alpha, \beta)$

**EDIT**
By the way searching for numerical solutions, I found this topic which is exactly the
same problem : [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804995/find-the-two-points-where-the-shortest-distance-occurs-on-two-lines)

Comment: The condition you've written is not needed for a collision. A collision can happen just as easily if the velocity vectors are not parallel.

Comment: But how close will these two particles get to each other if they do not collide?

Comment: @sea turtles, I've edited ;) thanks

Comment: According to the question, it indicates that at the time t1, one particle is at P1. But in your equation, t1 multiplying V1 seems to mean after it moves t1, it collides with the other particle. Plus, we can have a counterexample easily by putting the two particles on the same line and let V1 and V2 be parallel.

Comment: BTW, what does "∧" mean?

Comment: I don't know how to read anymore. I've edited ;)      $\wedge$ means cross product, I assume don't how what is it. It's the orthogonal vector to $\vec{V_1}$ and $\vec{V_2}$

Comment: I think I know how to solve it by looking at your equations. Thanks a lot for editing the answer :)

Comment: @Prince, Thanks for your patience ;)