# Find the distance between two lines

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

\begin{equation}
L_1:(x,y,z)=(-1,2,0)+t(0,-1,1) \\
L_2:(x,y,z)=(1,2,1)+s(1,-1,0)
\end{equation}

I have looked at multiple other questions but still can't solve it, the closest I got was this:

Generated the vector $L_1L_2=(2+s,-s+t,1-t)$. We know that this vector should be perpendicular to the lines, hence:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
L_1L_2 \cdot (0,-1,1)=0 \\
L_1L_2 \cdot (1,-1,0)=0
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
s-2t+1=0 \\
3t=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

This gives no solution and I have no idea what else to try.

I plotted the lines in Mathematica and they do not intersect nor are they parallell.

Comment: see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines#Distance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A point on $L_1$ has the form $(-1,2-t,t)$ and a point on $L_2$ has the form $(1+s,2-s,1)$. The square of the distance between these points is
$$ D = (2+s)^2 + (s-t)^2 + (t-1)^2.$$
The problem is to find the points where $D$ is minimized. $$\frac{\partial D}{\partial s} = 2(2+s) + 2 (s-t) = 4 + 4s - 2t
$$ $$\frac{\partial D}{\partial t} = -2(s-t) + 2(t-1) = -2s + 4t - 2.$$
The critical point is where both partial derivatives vanish, i.e., when $s = -1$ and $t=0$.

Plug these back into $D$ to get the minimum square distance $D = 1^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 = 3$. The distance between the lines is $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: So that makes the distance Sqrt[3]? If I insert s=-1 and t=0 into the vector L1L2 and calculate absolute value, correct?

Comment: Oops, I didn't finish the answer! I edited it.