# Shortest distance between skew line *segments*

Tags: geometry, vectors

The answer for the shortest distance between two skew lines has already been answered here and is also found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines#Nearest_Points).

However, I need to apply a further constraint. I need to find the shortest distance between two skew line *segments*. Or, if it is easier, two rays, whose starting points are $P_1$ and $P_2$. How can I modify the equations for $c_1$ and $c_2$ in the wiki link to account for this? Or is this a far more complicated problem?

Comment: I added [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2812513/318422) to this to the question this is marked a duplicate of, with a step by step procedure on how to find the closest points. It is trivial to modify the procedure to apply to rays, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Defining

$$
s_1(\lambda)=\lambda p_1+(1-\lambda)p_2\\
s_2(\mu) = \mu p_3+(1-\mu)p_4
$$

with $0\le \lambda\le 1$ and $0 \le \mu\le 1$ and with the help of four slack variables $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\epsilon_3,\epsilon_4$ to handle the inequality restrictions, the problem can be stated using the Lagrange Multipliers as follows

$$
L(\lambda, \mu, \eta,\epsilon) = \frac{1}{2}||s_1(\lambda)-s_2(\mu)||^2+\eta_1 (\lambda-\epsilon_1^2) +\eta_2(\mu-\epsilon_2^2)+\eta_3(\lambda-1+\epsilon_3^2)+\eta_4(\mu-1+\epsilon_4^2)
$$

with the stationary conditions

$$
\nabla L = 0
$$

or

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
(p_2+\lambda(p_1-p_2))(p_1-p_2)+\eta_1 + \eta_3 & = & 0\\
(p_4+\mu(p_3-p_4))(p_3-p_4)+\eta_2 + \eta_4 & = & 0\\
\lambda-\epsilon_1^2 & = & 0\\
\mu-\epsilon_2^2 & = & 0\\
\lambda-1+\epsilon_3^2 & = & 0\\
\mu-1+\epsilon_4^2 & = & 0\\
\eta_1\epsilon_1 & = & 0\\
\eta_2\epsilon_2 & = & 0\\
\eta_3\epsilon_3 & = & 0\\
\eta_4\epsilon_4 & = & 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Solving those conditions we get the possible stationary points.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks!

Comment: I found this very interesting, especially as it looks so *clean*, but as far as I can see, this system of equations has *lots* of solutions (Maple says 25 or so). Are you sure the first two equations in the system are correct? Anyway, in the [procedural](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2812513/318422) method, the solution is either directly obtained, or chosen between four possible point pairs. To me, it looks like the procedural method yields the answer with less computation/effort.

Comment: Yes. There are "duplicated" solutions due to the squared slack variables $\epsilon_i$. Those solutions contemplate all possible extremal situations. The qualification is made analyzing the values for $\epsilon_i,\eta_i$ so $\epsilon_i = 0 $ indicates that the restriction is actuating etc.

Comment: To me it gives with MATEMATICA a set of 9 possible extrema.